# Connect USB cable to GPIO pins on an Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, usb

**Electronics Newbie!!**

I want to connect a USB cable to my Uno's GPIO pins (and then connect it to a USB port on my computer). I have chopped off a USB cable from a keyboard, I read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/37066) and I'm hoping that the wires will be in the correct order (the keyboard was made by Dell). I'm a little confused about which wires go where.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The link is about power on a USB cable.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing that? Using 5v signals on the USB data lines isn't allowed in the USB-specification. You at least need to use a multi-meter to measure which wire, is connected to which pin on the USB socket, as the color-coding isn't always the same.

Comment: Take some help from attiny designs with USB; http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84663/firmware-circuit-of-attiny45-direct-usb-2-0-connection

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are confused about which wires go where is simply because the Uno has no connection on it for a USB cable's wires.

You cannot directly interface an Uno to a USB port without extra hardware.  What hardware you require depends on exactly what it is you think you are trying to achieve.

(There have been some attempts to create a USB device interface purely in software, but personally I wouldn't touch it with a barge pole - the GPIO of the Arduino is not electrically compatible with USB.)